# How to draw a gray square(200*100) on a white area(1280*720) with QGraphicsView in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, nodes, pyqt5, diagram

guys,what i want is to draw a gray square(200*100) on a white area(1280*720),But I don't know how to do it with QGraphicsView, can you help me?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import  sys


class AAA(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1280, 720)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:white')
        self.show()

        Xscene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(Xscene)

        gray_square=qDrawPlainRect(200,100)
        Xscene.addItem(gray_square)


A = QApplication(sys.argv)
aaa = AAA()
A.exec_()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: That still doesn't provide the information required for us to help - your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's not how this site works. You have provided an image of a GUI and expect other people to create this from scratch. There are plenty of tutorials on using pyqt5 e.g. [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) (simple google search). I recommend spending some time learning pyqt5 basics and then try to create this yourself

Comment: oh,i receive your teachings,but in fact i am a beginner and have spent countless hours studying this problem, but I still have no idea. I am not asking for code. Please don't misunderstand me

Comment: Please re-read my comments to understand what you need to provide, and then update your question so that we can help.

Comment: Sir, SO is not a free programming service, if you can not do this type of project start with the basics, create windows, use the buttons, customize events, read about signals and slots, etc. Not everything is learned in hours, you will never find an exact solution, if you do not want to do any of the above hire someone and pay them to do it since you do not want to schedule.

Comment: what i want is to draw a gray square(200*100) on a white area(1280*720),But I don't know how to do it with QGraphicsView, can you help me?[Code below]

Answer (score 0):

You were actually pretty close.  Try the following.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class AAA(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1280, 720)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:white')
        self.show()

        Xscene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(Xscene)

        # gray_square=qDrawPlainRect(200,100)
        gray_square = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 200, 100)
        gray_square.setPen(Qt.gray)
        gray_square.setBrush(QBrush((Qt.gray)))
        Xscene.addItem(gray_square)

A = QApplication(sys.argv)
aaa = AAA()
A.exec_()
```